# How many uniform packets will we have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

I came across the following problem:

A class got at a fundraising 120 kg flour, 72 kg sugar and 96 kg rice to offer to people that need these. How many uniform packets can they make and how many objects from each kind will each packet contain?

So each packet has to contain the same number of kilograms.

So, does it need to be 120/x=72/x=96/x=0 and we solve for x?

Comment: The question is ambiguous, since it does not say how many kilograms should go in each packet.  You have $288$ kg total, and the 3 ingredients are in the $15~:~12~:~9$ proportions.  So, you have to make sure that each packet has the 3 ingredients in those proportions.  This still leaves open, how many kilograms per packet.

Answer (score 1):

The question is indeed ambiguous, not the least because the quantities there (flour, sugar, rice) can obviously be divided into units smaller than a kilogram.

However, let's assume that the packet should contain the whole number of kilograms of all three staples. This means that, if we have $n$ packets, then all three numbers $120, 72, 96$ are divisible by $n$. This then in turn means that their $\gcd$ (greatest common divisor) is divisible by $n$. As $\gcd(120, 72, 96)=24$, we find that $24$ is divisible by $n$.

If you now want to distribute the goods to *the most people in need*, you want to maximise $n$ and you will go for $n=24$, with each packet containing $5$ kg of flour, $3$ kg of sugar and $4$ kg of rice.

Sadly, again the question is ambiguous in that it never says you want to maximise $n$. Without this condition, any divisor of $24$ would do. (In the extreme case, $n=1$ gives you one big packet with $120$ kg of flour, $72$ kg of sugar and $96$ kg of rice!)